# How can I integrate updating user list based on time when message arrives?

Tags: typescript, react-native, mobile, messaging, strapi

I'm writing an application in typescript using the React Native framework, but the user list remains constant, and I want the last user to go to the top. How can I do this in the user list?

> enter code here

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Explain what, how and where you want to use the user list. Display it on React?

Comment: In the messaging application, the messaged contacts should be listed from top to bottom according to the last message sent. We use strapi content management as a database for messaging.

Comment: Please add to your question details on how you use that messaging application. Angular/React/Vue, How you access Strapi API, etc. Remember, nobody will be able to help if the question is incomplete, hard to follow, you don't send code examples, explain in a detailed way what have you done to this point, and for sure what you expect, and where.
What you are explaining won't allow anybody to understand enough to help. You could even add Stackblitz code if it’s possible.